# Using Variable in Shell script as input for another command

Tags: linux, shell, variables

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker-compose -f /home/administrator/compose/docker-compose.yml up --build -d
OUTPUT=$(docker ps | grep 'nginx_custom' | awk '{ print $1 }')

echo $OUTPUT

sudo docker $OUTPUT nginx -s reload
```

This the the ID that get´s printed correctly in the console.

```
6e3b3aa3fbc4
```

This command works fine.

```
 docker exec 6e3b3aa3fbc4 nginx -s reload
```

However the variable seems not to get passed to the command here:

```
sudo docker $OUTPUT nginx -s reload
```

I am quite unfamiliar with the shell :(. How do I pass the variable to a command that is longer than just echo?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't *get passed to the command*? What error do you see? Have you tried running `set -x` before issuing `sudo docker ...` command to see what's going on?

Comment: Did you miss out `exec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `set -x` to the script and see what happens:
you can probably get rid of **grep** and incorporate it inside **awk**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo docker-compose -f /home/administrator/compose/docker-compose.yml up --build -d
OUTPUT=$(docker ps | awk '/ngnix_custom/{ print $1 }')

echo $OUTPUT

sudo docker $OUTPUT nginx -s reload
```